# Injecting NServiceBus using structuremap without global.asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api, structuremap, nservicebus

I am new to NServiceBus and struggling to inject IBus in my controller using structure map. Actually after doing a little research i found that we can inject it by putting below code in Application_Start event of global.asax -

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        Configure.With()
                 .Log4Net()
                 .StructureMapBuilder()
                 .XmlSerializer()
                 .MsmqTransport()
                 .IsTransactional(false)
                 .PurgeOnStartup(false)
                 .UnicastBus()
                 .ImpersonateSender(false)
                 .CreateBus();
    }
```

and in my controller I can use IBus as property or constructor injection:

```
private IBus Bus { get; set; }
    private ITest Test { get; set; }

    public MyLinkController(IBus bus, ITest test)
    {
        Bus = bus;
        Test = test;
    }
```

This works fine and inject bus without any problem. But my problem is I do not have control over global.asax, so i want to put the configuration somewhere else e.g. i tried putting it in structuremap registry like below:

```
For<IBus>().Use(
            () =>
                NServiceBus.Configure.With()
                                         .Log4Net()
                                         .StructureMapBuilder()
                                         .XmlSerializer()
                                         .IsTransactional(true)
                                         .PurgeOnStartup(false)
                                         .UnicastBus()
                                         .ImpersonateSender(false)
                                         .CreateBus()
                                         .Start()
                );
```

But it doesn't help. Looks like structure map needs to know the configuration before its own initialization.
So is there any way to do it without application_start event?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about not having control over the global.asax?  You must be making a call in Application_Start to configure StructureMap.  If this call is in a separate class (or even a static method), you could just configure the bus right before bootstrapping the container.

Comment: actually we are building separate modules, which are getting integrated in a common project say 'A'. Now as structure map is common to all modules so we kept it in 'A'. But we cannot put NServiceBus there as it is specific to one module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do it through structure-map itself. This is how I changed my structure-map registry:

```
public ServiceBusRegistry()
    {
        ForSingletonOf<IBus>().Use(
            NServiceBus.Configure.With()
                       .Log4Net()
                       .DefaultBuilder()
                       .XmlSerializer()
                       .MsmqTransport()
                       .IsTransactional(false)
                       .PurgeOnStartup(false)
                       .UnicastBus()
                       .ImpersonateSender(false)
                       .CreateBus()
                       .Start()
            );
    }
```

After putting this in Registry class of structure map, I am able to inject IBus in my controller:

```
public MyController(IRepository<Test, int> repository, IBus bus)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _bus = bus;
    }
```

Notice, here I used DefaultBuilder instead of StructureMapBuilder. I may try to improve it in further in future, But as of now its working fine for me.

**UPDATED** (after our project design changed):

Now we have a startup class in our API project(the project is ASP.NET web API) though we dont use global.asax's Application_start, we are able to put the startup code in this startup class:

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(WebApiPreStartup), "Start", Order = -999)] //make sure we are first

namespace ADP.DS.FrontOffice.Quoting.WebApi
{
    public static class WebApiPreStartup
    {
        public static void Start()
        {
            GlobalFilterConfig.Configure(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            BusConfig.Init();
        }
    }
}
```

and the configuration is in separate class:

```
public static void Init()
    {
        Configure.Serialization.SystemXml();
        Configure.ScaleOut(s => s.UseSingleBrokerQueue());
        var configUnicastBus = Configure.With()
            .StructureMapBuilder(ObjectFactory.Container)
            .UseTransport<NServiceBus.RabbitMQ>()
            .PurgeOnStartup(false)
            .UnicastBus();
        configUnicastBus.SendOnly();
    }
```

Comment: Have you made any changes to this implementation?

Comment: @JoshC. yes refactored it multiple times, as our project structure/design was keep changing. the current approach I updated in answer. However if you are looking for something else, i can try to help you if you can explain me.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I'm going to use MassTransit instead.