# StructureMap Exception Code: 202 No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily NServiceBus.IBus, NServiceBus, Version=2.6.0.1504

Tags: c#, javascript, json

Ex me,,,
I have a problem in my code,
I want to create POS in my program,,
but i have message error

> StructureMap Exception Code: 202 No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily NServiceBus.IBus, NServiceBus, Version=2.6.0.1504, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226

Here my script,,
can anyone help me,,,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Nancy;
using Nancy.Security;
using dokuku.pos.setting;
using StructureMap;
using NServiceBus;
using dokuku.sales.pos.messages;
using System.IO;
using Nancy.IO;

namespace dokuku.pos.web.modules
{
    public class PosSettingModule : Nancy.NancyModule
    {
        public PosSettingModule()
        {
            this.RequiresAuthentication();
            Post["card/addcard.json"] = p =>
            {
                string addCard = getJson(this.Request.Body);
                try
                {
                    POSCard cards = this.CardService().Insert(addCard, this.CurrentAccount().OwnerId);
                    PublishCardCreated(cards);
                    return Response.AsJson(cards);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return Response.AsJson(new { error = true, message = ex.Message });
                }
            };

private void PublishCardCreated(POSCard cards)
{
    ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IBus>().Publish(new CardCreated()
    {
        _id = cards._id,
        OwnerId = cards.OwnerId,
        Code = cards.Code,
        Name = cards.Name,
        Cost = cards.Cost,
        Discount = cards.Discount
    });
}
```

if i running this program and click create button,,
the system sent message error

> StructureMap Exception Code: 202 No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily NServiceBus.IBus, NServiceBus, Version=2.6.0.1504, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure structuremap to use a concrete instance. this is where you would set the configurationsof the bus. An example is in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256526/injecting-nservicebus-using-structuremap-without-global-asax)